# Set image in image-tag using rails 3.

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to set one image in image tag using RoR. That image path is fetched from DB and it has to set inside image tag.I have done some coding but unable to display that image.It also showing the following error.

Error:

```
SyntaxError in Homes#home

Showing C:/Site/swargadwara_puri/app/views/homes/home.html.erb where line #209 raised:

C:/Site/swargadwara_puri/app/views/homes/home.html.erb:209: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
...",:height => "140",:border => \'0\',:class =>\'borderblackdi...
...                               ^
C:/Site/swargadwara_puri/app/views/homes/home.html.erb:223: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
');     else 
  ^
Extracted source (around line #209):

206:         </div>
207:         <div class="tpaddingdiv1">
208:             <div class="col-md-4">
209:                 <div class="text-center bpaddingdiv1"><% image_tag("<%= @hcsy.D_Photo %>",:height => "140",:border => '0',:class =>'borderblackdiv' ) %></div>
210:                 <div class="fontweightbolddiv fontssizediv3 text-center bpaddingdiv1">Deceased Photo</div>
211:             </div>
212:             <div class="col-md-4">
```

Please check my below line.

```
<div class="text-center bpaddingdiv1"><% image_tag("<%= @hcsy.D_Photo %>",:height => "140",:border => '0',:class =>'borderblackdiv' ) %></div>
```

Please help me to resolve this error and display this image successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<div class="text-center bpaddingdiv1"><%= image_tag("#{@hcsy.D_Photo}",:height => "140",:border => '0',:class =>'borderblackdiv' ) %></div>
```

Changes are: `<% image_tag...` to `<%= image_tag` and `"<%= @hcsy.D_Photo %>"` to `"#{@hcsy.D_Photo}"`

**Edited**

change `"<%= @hcsy.D_Photo %>"` to `"/#{@hcsy.D_Photo}"`

Comment: Hi jon ,if i am putting "#{@hcsy.D_Photo}" for image path,Its true the path present in db is coming but at the setting time in image tag the path is setting like this "/assets/db path.....".Actually image is not stored in assets folder for that image also not coming.

Comment: No,same result.I think it is only accessing from assets folder in rails.I am giving my DB image path i.e-"C:\Site\swargadwara_puri\public\uploads\002.jpg".My image also present in public\uploads\ directory.Can you help me to set this as simple HTML image tag i.e(<img src="path" >).

Comment: using this path, never gone help you. you have to return path from your app, not whole dir path. rails never access files from outsider path.  so change `@hcsy.D_Photo` while storing in DB.